# How to convert to System.Int32 when doing a select from a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a DataTable that I've loaded from a CSV file using the [KBCsv library](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/). From what I can tell the columns are all numbers in the csv file and there aren't any null rows. I want to do a select on the data table with a query that I've created using String.Format. Here's the query:

```
String qry = String.Format("GRIDX = {0} AND GRIDY = {1} AND CONVERT([{2}], 'System.Int32') {3} {4}", xc, yc, _testDataColumn, _comparison, _threshold);
```

Where xc is a double, yc is a double, _testDataColumn is a string, _comparison is a string and _threshold is a double. The table.Select() method converts the string to:

```
GRIDX = 0 AND GRIDY = 4 AND CONVERT([ST DEVSSI(dBm)], 'System.Int32') = 5
```

I put that CONVERT in there because before I was getting a

> Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32

error message. I've looked at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac3d5644-f8f6-42fd-8829-9452763d364d/cannot-perform-operation-on-systemstring-and-systemint32?forum=transactsql) for help. I don't understand how that last column (ST DEVSSI) became a string. Am I doing the conversion correctly? Is there another way to take care of such errors?

If you run the code with the sample [CSV File](http://1drv.ms/1mE1OLa) you should get the same error when it searches for coordinates (0, 4) so it looks like the problem is near the end of the CSV file, but I'm still not sure.

A full example of my code:

```
using Kent.Boogaart.KBCsv;
using Kent.Boogaart.KBCsv.Extensions;
using Kent.Boogaart.KBCsv.Extensions.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestCSVReader
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private String _csvFilePath;
    private String _tempFilePath;
    private StreamReader _streamReader;
    private HeaderRecord _headerRecord = new HeaderRecord();
    private Double _threshold = 5;
    private String _testDataColumn = "ST DEVSSI(dBm)";
    private String _comparison = "=";
    private String[] coordinates = { "0,1", "0,2", "0,4", "1,1", "1,2", "1,3", "1,4"};

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _tempFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + @"\temp.csv";
        _csvFilePath = "CSV FILE PATH";

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(_csvFilePath))
        {
            HeaderRecord headerRecord = new HeaderRecord(streamReader.ReadLine().Split(','));

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            using (var reader = new CsvReader(streamReader))
            {
                reader.HeaderRecord = headerRecord;
                table.Fill(reader);
            }

            foreach (String coordinate in coordinates)
            {
                var xy = coordinate.Split(',');
                double xc = Double.Parse(xy[0]);
                double yc = Double.Parse(xy[1]);

                String qry = String.Format("GRIDX = {0} AND GRIDY = {1} AND [{2}] {3} {4}", xc, yc, _testDataColumn, _comparison, _threshold);
                var results = table.Select(qry);

                if (results.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found a match for {0}, {1}", xc, yc));
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Found a match for {0}, {1}", xc, yc));
                }
            }
        }

        _streamReader.Close();
    }
}
}
```

That sample code gives me the error above so I attempted to use a CONVERT in the query statement, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: If you want to consider something a bit more palatable than datatables, check out [LINQ to CSV](https://github.com/mperdeck/LINQtoCSV).

Comment: And would you please clarify - what are you passing this string to?  It would help if you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've added a code sample. I've tried using LINQ to CSV but the problem is the program may need to handle many different CSV files, so I can't create models for LINQ dynamically without knowing the column names before runtime.

Comment: I can kindof see what you're doing now, but I still can't reproduce the problem because your code isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Specifically, you don't have values for `_headerRecord` and `_threshold`, and you didn't show an example of the CSV data itself.  There's also a lot of other noise in this code, such as using a `Window`, variable names that don't align (`_testDataColumn` vs `_dataColumn`, and the code can't compile because the `DataTable` constructor is missing parenthesis.

Comment: Also I had to figure out that I needed *two* nuget packages, as you're using the main `Kent.Boogaart.KBCsv` library as well as the `Kent.Boogaart.KBCsv.Extensions.Data` library.

Comment: Please consider the great advice in the ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article.  Specifically the advice on *"Restart from scratch"*.  If we can't just copy and past your example into VS and run it, we're not likely going to be able to help you here.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I was hoping that I wouldn't need to load the CSV file up for legal reasons, but I'll work on creating one that I can. Hopefully, I can get it uploaded here in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to show your full csv file - just a small example that is similar enough to reproduce the problem you are describing.

Comment: Alright, so I've added a minimal, complete, and verifiable example (hopefully :D). Are you able to get the same error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56442/discussion-between-witecastle-and-matt-johnson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, but to fix the specific problem you're reporting:

- When building the query string, make sure to include a decimal point for the threshold parameter value.  The simplest way is `{4:f}` in the format string.

The reason this works is because the CSV library you're using just makes all of the values in the data table have string types.  When you filter, each value is being converted from a string to the type of *the value it is being compared against*.  So if you compare `"3"` with `3`, the string is converted to an integer and it works.  But comparing `"3.5"` with `3` won't just return false, it fails because `"3.5"` can be converted to an integer.  Comparing against a value with a decimal point will convert the string to a double instead of an integer, and then it all works.

It's going to be slow as all heck though.  It's parsing strings like crazy here, and the data table is loaded into memory.  There are much better approaches - like loading the CSV into a real database that has indexes.

Comment: Also, you can just call `reader.ReadHeaderRecord();` instead of working with the stream yourself - but that's not related to the problem you reported.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue, thanks for everything. I had to use the streamreader because the original CSV file has an unconventional header. There are two extra lines before the actual header, and the headers are each split across two lines.

Answer (score 0):

In C# there are several methods to perform string to numeric type conversion:

Sample 1:

```
    string _str ="12.25";
   // throws exception if fail, relatively slow in case of invalid input
    double _dbl = Convert.ToDouble(_str);
```

Sample 2:

```
string _str ="12.25";
// throws exception if fail, relatively slow in case of invalid input
double _dbl = Double.Parse(_str);
```

Sample 3:

```
string _str ="12.25";
double _dbl;
// true if conversion OK, false is fail;
// very fast compare to other two: (1) and (2)
Double.TryParse(_str,out _dbl);
```

Hope this will help.